# error with sent tail logs telegraf to influxdb. Parse nginx proxy manager logs access

Tags: parsing, nginx, influxdb, telegraf, grok

i try to use telegraf to [inputs.tail] with nginx proxy manager sent logs to influxDB_v2.

when i try to match pattern

nginx.conf

```
log_format proxy '$status - $request_method - $scheme - $host - $request_uri - $remote_addr - $server';
```

and the log is like this

```
302 - GET - https - cloud.workwithme.es - index.html - 10.10.0.70 - 10.10.0.250
200 - GET - https - pe.workwithme.es - /api2/json/nodes/pve-work/qemu/778/status/current - 10.10.0.31 - 10.10.0.10
```

and the config of telegraf.conf is this:

```
[[inputs.tail]]
files = ["/srv/docker/npm/data/logs/proxy-host-*_access.log"]
data_format = "grok"
grok_patterns='%{NUMBER:codigo}\s-\s%{WORD:metodo}\s-\s%{WORD:protocolo}\s-\s%{WORD:host}\s-\s%{WORD:ruta}\s-\s%{IPORHOST:direccion_cliente}\s-\s%{IPORHOST:direccion_servidor}'
```

and the debugg log of telegraf says:

```
2023-05-09T18:24:10Z D! [inputs.tail] Tail added for "/srv/docker/npm/data/logs/proxy-host-6_access.log"
2023-05-09T18:24:10Z E! [inputs.tail] Creating parser: line 11349: (grok.Parser.Patterns) cannot unmarshal TOML string into []string
```

do you know something about this or how i can fix this?